# the crash log EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) iTunes connect

Tags: ios

i have test my app on my device it run. But when it submit it to app store, i get a crash log. I desymbolicate it and it show something wrong in line 70 in my code with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) error. 
I known it is the memory management problem. But it don't knwon what wrong in my code:
the line 70:

```
69: distanceLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:24];
70: distanceLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 1);
71: distanceLabel.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height-20);
72: distanceLabel.color = ccBLACK;
73: [self addChild:distanceLabel z:20];
```

And in the header file i declare the distanceLabel:

```
 @property(nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) CCLabelTTF * distanceLabel;
```

So what is problem in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your variable `distanceLabel` is set to `__unsafe_unretained` it is getting released right after being created.

```
//Here you create an object and assign it to the variable distanceLabel
distanceLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:24];

//Now, since your self.distanceLabel is unretianed, 
//the object you just created has a retain count of 0
//Therefore memory management releases the object as it 
//no longer has a retianed reference to it
//This line is now trying to access an object that doesn't exist
70: distanceLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 1);
```

If you change your property to `retain` or `strong`:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) CCLabelTTF * distanceLabel;
```

then your object will have a reference count of 1 just after creation and not get destroyed by ARC's garbage collection.

EDIT: more info.

ARC is not a real time garbage collector.  It works when it needs to, but leaves you to your devices when it doesn't need to.  Your code is wrong and dangerous because of this.  That view could be released at any time since it's retain count is 0.  It could crash, it could run.  iTunes Connect just found this possible crash and said "Hey, this will ruin your app, fix it please".

Comment: thaks a lot, i understand

Comment: i will try it. And more stupid question: why my code is wrong but it can run very well on my iPhone and iPod? I only find it through iTunes connect.

Comment: @user3243028 Updated my answer with an explanation of why it didn't crash when debugging.

Comment: @user3243028 Make sure to mark the answer that helped solve your problem for anyone in the future that has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to change in .h:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) CCLabelTTF * distanceLabel;
```

and .m:

```
@synthesize distanceLabel
```

and ini method init:

```
self.distanceLabel=[[CCLabelTTF alloc] init];
```

and then you affect information to your distanceLabel

```
 self.distanceLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:24];
 self. distanceLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 1);
 self.distanceLabel.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height-20);
 self.distanceLabel.color = ccBLACK;
 [self addChild:self.distanceLabel z:20];
```

and in your dealloc method:

```
[self.distanceLabel release];
```

i hope this work

Comment: but i use ARC, so do i need alloc and release? and the difference between distanceLabel and self.distanceLable. And the hardest is i can't reproduce the crash log, it run well on my device and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

1) check distanceLabel value; 
2) replace ccp with the original CGPointMake(1.0,1.0)
3) Does your distanceLabel really have anchorPoint  property?